# Why JVM is called an abstract machine?

Tags: jvm

I'm a beginner in learning java.

And, I've following questions on JVM:

I know that abstraction means hiding unnecessary details and showing the required details only.

Why JVM is called an abstract machine?

Which information/implementation details it hides?

And, which details/functionality it shows?

Answer (score 1):

It abstracts the hardware platform and memory usage details.

Answer (score 0):

An *abstract machine* is a theoretical model of a physical machine. The JVM is a virtual machine-- a software implementation of a physical computer. The respective uses of *abstract* that you cite carry different practical meanings.